# Proving a function has a limit $6$ at infinity, when the derivative approaches zero and the sequence $f(n)$ approaches $6$

Tags: real-analysis, calculus

Let $f: \Bbb R \to \Bbb R$ be a differentiable function that satisfies:

- $\lim_{x\to\infty}f'(x)=0$
- $\lim_{n\to\infty}f(n)=6$ ($n \in \Bbb N$)

Prove $\lim_{x\to\infty}f(x)=6$.

I managed the prove that the function must either approach $6$ at infinity, or not have a limit at all at infinity, how do I proceed?

Comment: Use Mean Value Theorem.

Comment: I'm not sure how that would work here....

Comment: Any $x$ lies between two integers.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The Mean Value theorem is the way to go here. I will write just an outline of a proof, but it can be made more concrete with epsilons and deltas and the like.

Take some sufficiently large $x$. Then there exists some $n\in\mathbb N$ such that $n\leq x < n+1$. Also, the Mean value theorem tells you that for some $c\in[n, x]$, you have $$f'(c) = \frac{f(x)-f(n)}{x-n}$$ or, in other words, $$f(x)-f(n) = (x-n)\cdot f'(c).$$  The right hand side of the equation is small, because $f'$ is small, and $f(n)$ is also close to $6$, so $f(x)$ is close to $6$.